# MySQL DELIMITER syntax errors

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, delimiter

This MySQL script installs multiple triggers.

It works on one machine running MySQL 5.0.51b-community. On another machine running MySQL 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) it fails, with this error message, which seems to be related to the `DELIMITER // ... // DELIMITER`; syntax :

> **ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 272: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER; DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name; DELIMITER' at line 1**

The script syntax (summarised) is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  -- Trigger logic goes here
END //
DELIMITER;

-- More trigger drop/create statements follow
```

What is wrong with the script, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
DELIMITER ;
```

not

```
DELIMITER;
```

You're actually specifying `;` as an argument to the `DELIMITER` command, so not having the space there may be confusing it.

Answer (score 4):

You need a space between 'DELIMITER' and ';'

```
DELIMITER ;
# not:
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as an add-on, for someone else:

The delimiter is required to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.

I am sure it should solve the purpose.

```
DELIMITER +
CREATE TRIGGER STUDENT_INSERT_TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON FSL_CONNECTIONS 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO STUDENT_AUDIT 
SET STUDENT_ID = NEW.STUDENT_ID, 
MAC_ADDRESS = NEW.MAC_ADDRESS,
IPADDRESS = NEW.IPADDRESS, 
EMAIL_ID = NEW.EMAIL_ID , 
START_TIME=NEW.START_TIME, 
END_TIME=NEW.END_TIME, 
STATUS=NEW.STATUS; 
END; +
```

From the above when we use a DELIMITER. It should be in the form of

```
DELIMITER +
--
BLOCK OF SQL WHATEVER YOU WANT TO MENTION
--
+
```

Answer (score 1):

In the version of MySql I use the same error occurs when using the delimiter command, but this version handles the delimiter ";" for statements and delimiter "|" for stored procedures and functions, which i think solves the problem; try this:

`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name;`

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  -- Trigger logic goes here
END |

-- other statements or functions here

Comment: What version would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm having similar problems. I do a mysqldump from Debian Lenny running 5.0.51 and try importing to OpenSolaris running 5.0 and get the same error. And I have DELIMITER ;

Version conflict?

Comment: It seemed to be related to versions for us, one version worked with no semicolon, another worked with just a semicolon, and another required a semicolon and no space.

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER age_verified
BEFORE INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
IF new.age<0 THEN SET new.age=0
END IF;//

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).