# Mysql Before Insert Trigger SET fails

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, insert

I have fairly simple basic table which I will populate with CHAR(4) primary keys.

These values are selected from a **chars** table with a subquery.

I want to set up a **BEFORE INSERT** query so that each time I **INSERT** a new record from PHP, the **id** field should get the generated CHAR(4) from subquery.

"ASDF","This is body text", "1970-01-01 01:01:01"

so on.

I'm pulling my hair out with this trigger.

```
DELIMETER |
CREATE TRIGGER messages_newid 
BEFORE INSERT ON messages
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = (SELECT CONCAT(a.val,b.val,c.val,d.val)
    FROM chars AS a
    JOIN chars AS b
    JOIN chars AS c
    JOIN chars AS d
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1);
END
|
```

Here follows the table structure of **messages**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` varchar(4) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` text collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the trick **chars** table I have found within another answer, which is used for CHAR(4) randomness

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chars` (
  `val` char(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What does this have to do with privileges?

**EDIT** Here's the new error code

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

means that to execute `create trigger` you must have `SUPER` privilege. Login as user who has such permission and re-run your query.

Some side notices.
   The trigger you are creating will not probably work as you want: you cannot just write `INSERT INTO messages(body, created) VALUES(some_text, some_datetime)`, you will have to do `INSERT INTO messages(id, body, created) VALUES('text', some_text, some_datetime);` (note, you provide a value for 'id' which will be changed by your trigger); otherwise you will have 'Field id doesn't have a default value error' since mysql checks not null constraint before launching your trigger.

Finally, the value of your primary key is random; it does not mater for MyISAM tables, but if you later decide to switch to INNODB engine, you will have performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** It seems all the linked examples use `//` for the  delimiter instead of  `|`.  You might want to try that and see if it works better.

**Edit 2:** If you are running this in PHPMyAdmin from cPanel, you need to control the Delimiter from the [little text box Delimeter option](http://pricetalk.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/mysql-mysql-50-reference-manual-1731-trigger-syntax/) below the SQL query window, not by the `DELIMETER` command which it seems to ignore.

Also, as I was [looking](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5337) [through](http://technikhil.wordpress.com/2007/03/13/nikhil-in-mysql-land-2-2/) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102109/mysql-delimiter-syntax-errors), it seems you need to reset the `DELIMITER` back to `;` at the end of the trigger definition, or it seems to remain globally as `|` and messes up the future queries, including the contents of the trigger itself when it runs:

```
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMETER |
CREATE TRIGGER messages_newid
BEFORE INSERT ON messages
FOR EACH ' at line 1 ` didn't change the situation.

Comment: @Cengiz: Hmm, all the examples I linked use `//` for the delimiter.  Maybe it works better with that, you can try it instead of `|`?

Comment: @mellamokb Changing the delimeter to `//` gave another error like `ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
STR: //
SQL: DELIMETER //
CREATE TRIGGER messages_newid 
BEFORE INSERT ON messages
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = (SELECT CONCAT(a.val,b.val,c.val,d.val)
    .......
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1);DELIMETER //.......`

Comment: @Cengiz: Also, note my edit above. If you do use `DELIMETER |`, I think you have to mark the end of that statement using the  previous delimeter `;`, like this: `DELIMETER |;` <-- add `;`.  See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267172/mysql-delimiter-error.  Try that and let me know the result.

Comment: @mellamokb That just makes the delimeter 2 chars `|;` therefore, is a wrong use of `DELIMETER` method.

Comment: @Cengiz: Whoops, you are correct.   Didn't read the post fully :).  Looking at the comments, my next guess is that you need a newer version of MySQL.  OP mentions they have 5.0.67 which didn't work, but 5.0.81 does work.  Can you check the version of MySQL that you have?

Comment: @mellamokb `protocol_version 10
version 5.0.91-community-log
version_comment MySQL Community Edition (GPL)`

Comment: @Cegniz: Are you running this in like PhpMyAdmin by chance?  I was getting the same error message when I tested it in my cPanel's PhpMyAdmin, then I noticed there is a Delimeter option at the bottom of the screen. I think that is actually where you change the delimiter and it seems to ignore the `DELIMETER` command in PhpMyAdmin.  See for example here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Trigger