# Trigger for updating table in another database

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm creating trigger that updates table in another database. 
This is trigger syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tbltrigger_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `tbl` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE db2.tbl1 SET db2.tbl1.Status = db1.tbl.Status WHERE db2.tbl1.OrderID = db1.tbl.OrderID;
END
```

But when I make change on Status field in db1.tbl I get error message 1054: Unkown column
'db2.tbl.OrderID' in 'where clause' even field exist in that table in db2.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

[link1 - Trigger insert into new database](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,426213,426213)

You might want to check this one as well

[link2 - stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526780/want-to-write-trigger-for-two-different-databases-in-mysql)

p.s. - if the DB's are on different hosts , you probably need some sort of (custom) replication or [federated-storage-engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: I've already saw this. There is no need for replication because both databases are on the same server.