# mysql stored procedure syntax inconsistency

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a stored procedure which is syntactically acceptable on my local PC, where I have MySQL workbench 5.2.44 and I think my local version of MySQL is 5.5.29 judging by the folder names. Here is the code, which I have reduced to a minimum for illustration

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_insert_booking_test_2`(
        IN  p_dtmTimeSlot DATETIME  
     )

BEGIN 

     INSERT INTO tblBookings (dtmTimeSlot)
     SELECT p_dtmTimeSlot
     FROM tblBookings
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblBookings WHERE dtmTimeSlot = p_dtmTimeSlot) LIMIT 1;

END$$
```

As you can see, I am trying to ensure I do not create two bookings in the same time slot. Yes, I have a constraint on the table to do this also. Belt & braces. When I try to add this procedure on my remote host (running MySQL version 5.1.68-cll), it says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12

Line 12 is the WHERE NOT EXISTS line. I have tried removing LIMIT 1, that makes no difference. Is there a way to write the query so that MySQL 5.1 will accept it?

Comment: The Last Line should be `END $$` (Space mission) And the line missing after the last line:

`DELIMITER ;`

Comment: A space missing after `END`

Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102109/mysql-delimiter-syntax-errors

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_insert_booking_test_2`(
    IN  p_dtmTimeSlot DATETIME  
 )

BEGIN 

 INSERT INTO tblBookings (dtmTimeSlot)
 SELECT p_dtmTimeSlot
 FROM tblBookings
 WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM tblBookings WHERE dtmTimeSlot = p_dtmTimeSlot LIMIT 1);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

here somevalue is that you want to insert.

Comment: Neither of the suggestions work. The suggested answer breaks one SQL statement into two unrelated statements which change the semantics completely. The suggestion that a space is missing does not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

i needed to add

DELIMITER ;

to the end of the code as shown. No idea why.