# Mysql three TRIGGERs to single trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

My Mysql Table doesn't support create multiple triggers . but i have 3 triggers for three update queries, how can i run these triggers using single trigger,

> ERROR  :#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple
>   triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

thanks

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `update_yeild2` BEFORE UPDATE ON `today_plan`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.yeild = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.yeild 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0)


CREATE TRIGGER `update_yeild1` BEFORE UPDATE ON `today_plan`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.temp = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.temp 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0)

CREATE TRIGGER `update_yeild0` BEFORE UPDATE ON `today_plan`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.kiln = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.kiln 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0)
```

**UPDATED CODE :**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_yeild2` BEFORE UPDATE ON `today_plan`
 FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

SET NEW.yeild = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.yeild 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);


  SET NEW.temp = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.temp 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);

  SET NEW.kiln = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.kiln 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);

END
```

thanks

**Working Code**  : thanks RandomSeed

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `update_yeild2` BEFORE UPDATE ON `today_plan`
 FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

SET NEW.yeild = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.yeild 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);


  SET NEW.temp = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.temp 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);

  SET NEW.kiln = COALESCE((SELECT kiln_master.kiln 
                   FROM kiln_master
                   WHERE NEW.itemno = kiln_master.item  
                   AND  NEW.pattern = kiln_master.pattern
                   LIMIT 1), 0);

END

//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the three triggers' operations in one single trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER (...)
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.yeild = (...) ;
    SET NEW.temp = (...) ;
    SET NEW.kiln = (...) ;
END ;
```

Comment: Oh now I get it, you were probably looking for the `BEGIN ... END` thingy.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: @Prabath This is a new error (syntax error). Please post your current code.

Comment: thanks. i have added my current code into main post.. please refer.

Comment: Have you wrapped your trigger definition between proper `DELIMITER` clauses? When defining multi-statements procedures (or triggers in this case), you need to tell the parser not to interpret the `;` as the end of your defining statement. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger) for more information. Could this be the cause?

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102109/mysql-delimiter-syntax-errors) too.

Comment: thnks RandomSeed . DELIMITER  is the missing part.. now working.. :) :) :)